# SVN vs CVS repo

Tags: svn, cvs

What SVN repos are worth looking into.

I would like, security, privacy, easy to use and free.

I have some code I want to backup and thought SVN could be a good way to go, rather than backup onto disk.

Which SVN could you recommend. I would also like one with a nice web UI and the ability to document the project. It would only be for max 2 users.

Also what is the difference between SVN and CVS?

Thanks

Comment: You can have pick any two: secure, easy, free. I don't know of any way of getting all 3.

Comment: Get a DVCS like Mercurial or Git.  You'll thank me later.

Comment: What is DVCS and why will I thank you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Mercurial and enjoy it very much. You can get a free Bitbucket account and start storing your repos in the cloud.

There's a really good free video on [tekpub for Mercurial and Codeplex](http://tekpub.com/view/dotnet-oss/7). It takes you through all the basics and will be close to how Bitbucket works.

Check out the http://hginit.com link as another good resource.

I was using SVN on my local box to store my personal work but no more. With Bitbucket & Mercurial I won't have to worry about my local box dying and making sure I had everything backed up....

You could also look into Git. The basic gist I have found/heard is Mercurial is a little easier to work with but not as powerful as Git. However, both are excellent choices.

Bottom line is you can't go wrong with either Hg (Mercurial) or Git but I would go with Hg unless you needed some of the advanced features which sounds like you don't.

Learning SVN isn't necessarily bad as there are a lot of Organizations using it but I would really concentrate on Distributed Version Control Systems instead. They really are the future. :-)

Comment: I wouldnt use a local SVN, I would look at a service. I am still studying software engineering now and If you say it is the future I better get on it.Thing is I have a number of Iphone apps and games in development and want to back them up somewhere online. As well as uni projects I will need for my CV. Is Mercurial safe and secure with private access? thanks

Comment: Okey, SO it is a local server architecture like Git. I purposefully want to use it as a backup(on a server). Any preferable SVN services?

Comment: You can convert SVN to Mercurial.  That will help you keep your current repo info while moving to another tool. Just google SVN to Mercurial and you'll find a lot of info on it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

git + Github. There's is imo no reason to start with svn now, with much better alternatives available.

Comment: What are the much better alternatives to SVN?

Comment: I don't think they could be directly compared. SVN is server based, while git or mercurial are distributed.

Comment: alJaree: No, CVS is public projects.  (Because pserver has terrible security!  Get it? :-)

Comment: @alJaree , you have have private repositories with pricing

Answer (score 0):

If you want something where you can centrally control users and read/write rights, use Subversion. It's free, relatively simple and secure (provided you use https://). See [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache) for a guide on setting up Apache, or use [visualsvn server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server) for Windows setups that help you get a server up and running pretty quick.